# Accessing Public Page Data with Facebook Graph API for Pages I Don't Own

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api, access-data-project

I'm working on a project that involves utilizing the Facebook Graph API and Instagram API. I'm interested in obtaining public data from a Facebook page using the Graph API, even if I don't own the page. Is it possible to achieve this, and if so, what are the necessary steps or considerations?

Comment: You would have to get the Page Public Content Access and/ or the Page Public Metadata Access feature approved for your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access/